# Validation Rules

Tags: validation, record-type

I want to write a validation rule for different record types with different conditions.

*Example*: I want to validate the selling price of flat and penthouse records types which are on a single object. For that I need to validate the following conditions on `selling price`

1. selling price for **flat** should *not be less than 75lakh*.
2. selling price of **penthouse** should *not be greater than 6crores*.

How would I write a validation rule that satisfies both conditions?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. It is not a purpose of this site to provide solutions for requirements; one of the things we always look for is *your effort so far*. Please make an effort to research your problem and start an implementation before asking. See [ask].

Comment: Another user has asked [exactly the same question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294173/flats-and-penthouse-price?noredirect=1&lq=1). If you are working on the same project, please coordinate. If this is some type of exam or interview question, please do not post it on Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
OR( 
   AND(
       RecordType.Name = 'flat',
       SellingPrice__c < 7500000
   ), 
   AND(
       RecordType.Name = 'penthouse',
       SellingPrice__c > 60000000
   ) 
)
```

Please replace the API Name of field 'SellingPrice__c' and developer names of the record types 'flat' and 'penthouse' according to you.